# How to ignore empty list when using pyspark `map` function?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

Suppose I am executing a simple pyspark script `data_rdd.map(some_fun).toDF()`, where `data_rdd` contains just a sequence of records to be processed by `some_fun`. `some_fun` will return a list, and sometimes it is an empty list. An example output is shown below, where you can see the empty list.

My question is, is there anyway to filter out these empty list without using the expensive `where` or `filter`? Anyway to make `map` itself ignore the empty lists? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD#flatMap`

```scala
data_rdd.flatMap(x => {
  val res = some_fun(x)
  if (res.nonEmpty) Seq(res) else Seq.empty
})
```

This does the operation in one function, but still expensive in terms of memory consumption.
Using `filter` is better in terms of time taken and resource utilization, given that it happens via codegen